# EntityFramework.Core: correct way to update entity's deeply nested properties given a DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly do a deep update of an Entity given a DTO.

I have a class:

```
DummyModel
 |- List<Level1>

Level1:
 |- List<Level2>

Level2:
 |- List<Level3>

Level3:
 |- Flat properties
```

I attempted:

- Use AgileMapper library which has a ["Id-Aware" update feature](https://agilemapper.readthedocs.io/Performing-Updates/): this works perfectly fine but it's a major overhead
- Manually updating entities by creating a recursive function which "Id-Aware" updates the list by aligning entities using the Id and manually adding/removing/updating. [Code](https://github.com/amir734jj/EF-update-dto/blob/1de81b9a59ac8954619f853f39617e76da1799f3/Core/Extensions/ListExtension.cs#L20)
- Using: `context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto)` correctly understand when I shuffle the list and nothing actually changes but it does not track level 2 or level 3 deep changes.

I'm wondering what is the correct approach? using 1) AutoMapper or AgileMapper, 2) manually updating entities 3) creating a view model out of entities mapping between entity and view models?

Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you.

I made [this repo](https://github.com/amir734jj/EF-update-dto/tree/1de81b9a59ac8954619f853f39617e76da1799f3) as a "test jig".

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore

Comment: I already know about it. My question is what's the correct way? does EF has a built-in solution? why `context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(dto)` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: The thing is, similar questions get asked _all_ of the time. So go through them and choose whatever works best for you.